# Understanding pipes: lines read and order of execution

Tags: macos, bash, pipe

Say I run the command

```
decode_input < input.txt | intermediate_calcs | decode_output > output.txt
```

where each program reads one line of input from stdin, and outputs one line on stdout.

How exactly does the OS run/manage all these operations?

1) Does `decode_input` first run and read N lines from `input.txt`, then all the output is piped to `intermediate_calcs`, which reads and processes N lines, which is finally piped to `decode_output`?

OR:
2) Does `decode_input` read **one** line from `input.txt`, process it, have it's output piped to `intermediate_calcs`, which again pipes its **one** line of output to `decode_output` and then the first line of output is written to `output.txt`.
Then this process is repeated for the N lines in `input.txt`?

So, if the process proceeds in serial, like in 2), this may be very slow if one of the intermediate steps is much slower than the other? E.g. if `decode_input` takes the most time, then the 2 other processes has to wait for `decode_input` to produce their input for every single line in `input.txt?`

Thank you

Comment: They run in parallel. Proof: `tail -f file | grep some_text`. Before tail completes, grep has already started its work..

Comment: If `decode_input` is slow, how can the other processes **not wait** for it?

Comment: The other processes will consume ```decode_input``` output as soon as it is available. For instance: if they work on a line by line basis, as soon the ```decode_input``` prints a line, the ```intermediate_calcs``` will start reading those lines and produce some output themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as per 2).  But this really depends on how each process is written.  Generally the process will use some sort of `getline()` method where it will effectively block until it's received a lines-worth of input.  However it's possible to write the process using non-blocking I/O or multiple threads that will process each character of input and produce appropriate output.

Therefore it's not really an O/S issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

All the commands in a pipeline are started concurrently. The shell uses `pipe()` and `fork()` system calls to set up file descriptors and unnamed pipes accordingly so each process can read from `stdin` and write to `stdout`.

And just as you assumed, the pipeline can be only as fast as its slowest process, so in your example, if `decode_input` is slow, the other two processes will spend much time waiting for input.

But this is not a bad thing: If this is implemented correctly, it will cost virtually no CPU time.

Comment: What do you mean by implemented correctly? Do you mean the way I should implement each of the separate programs (decode_input etc) or how I should issue the pipe commands? Thanks

Comment: @luffe: No, this remark was more academic. Almost all programs out there are implemented "correctly". What I meant by that: A naive approach would be to periodically check an I/O buffer in a loop ([busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting)) which would consume CPU time. The operating system and most programming frameworks therefore offer blocking `read()` operations which suspend a thread or process until I/O is available, so that is how it is done.